# How to append dynamic value in retrofit Android url without &

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to have in final :
https://api.ocs.fr/apps/v2/contents?search=title=value
where is value dynamic

my code :

```kotlin
@GET("contents?search=")
    suspend fun getProgrammes(
        @Query("title") title: String
    )
BASE_URL = "https://api.ocs.fr/apps/v2/"
```

I get in results https://api.ocs.fr/apps/v2/contents?search=&title=rouge

I don't want the "&", any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

because `=` is not a valid character for a query parameter. So your url should encode it to send.

```
https://api.ocs.fr/apps/v2/contents?search=title%3Dvalue
```

Your Retrofit should be

```
@GET("contents")
suspend fun getProgrammes(
    @Query("search") value: String
)
```

Then call

```
getProgrammes("title=value")
```